# Integrate $x^7 e^{-x/2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I tried doing this by integration by parts in which I assigned:

$u=x^7\\
du=7x^6\\
v=-2e^{-x/2}\\
dv=e^{-x/2}$

I also tried this by some u substitution where I said:

$u=-x/2\\
du=-0.5dx\\
-2u=x$

This makes it so that I'm integrating essentially $e^u u^7$. Either way it doesn't look easier; am I missing something? What would you suggest?

Comment: It must be $du=7x^6\, dx$. You need $dx$.

Comment: Integration by parts made an integral of $x^7e^{-x/2}$ into an integral of $x^6e^{-x/2}$ (with some constant factors and an $x^7e^{-x/2}$ term outside the integral). Repeat that process, and eventually you're left with integrating just $e^{-x/2}$.

Comment: $u = x^8$ then $du = 8x^7 dx$ so we must integrate $\frac 18 e^{-\sqrt[8]v/2} dv$ might be easier?

Comment: Tabular/table integration, by parts, is a method that may be used.

Answer (score 1):

**hint:**

This is standard, and the form of the answer is known: it is
$$p(x)\mathrm e^{-\tfrac x2},\enspace\text{where $p(x)$ is  a polynomial of degree $7$.}$$
So apply a method of undetermined coefficients: set
$$p(x)=a_0x^7+a_1x^6+a_2x^5+a_3x^4+a_4x^3+a_5x^2+a_6x+a_7$$
and write the condition for $\;\Bigl(p(x)\mathrm e^{-\tfrac x2}\Bigr)'=x^7 \mathrm e^{-\tfrac x2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Intergrate $-2x^7.de^{-x/2}$ to reduce the exponent of x by one.
Repeat as necessary.  That is how the undetermined coefficients work.